# What is the essential difference between `tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d` and `tf.nn.max_pool`?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I found two functions, `tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d` and `tf.nn.max_pool`, for max pooling in TensorFlow.

`tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d` seems to be a wrapper of `tf.nn.max_pool`, but I could not understand what is the advantage of using `tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d.

What is the essential difference between `tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d` and `tf.nn.max_pool`?

Resources:

- document of `tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d`

  - https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#max_pool2d
- document of `tf.nn.max_pool`

  - https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#max_pool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, functionally, there is no "essential" difference between them, except for some minor differences between their signatures(`ksize`, `strides`, etc.)

But please pay attention, `tf.contrib` is an unstable collection of some high-level functions contributed from various sources, thus might be modified or even removed in future versions.